# What is this disease on my Christmas Palm, and how do I treat it?

Tags: diseases, fungus, palm

I bought this Christmas Palm 10 weeks ago, and it was healthy and full, with no signs of disease. I'm in Ft. Lauderdale, zone 10. I placed the palm on my sometimes windy, south-facing balcony. I watered it when the soil felt dry to the touch -- about 2.5 quarts most days -- until the water ran out the bottom (no saucer). It developed brown spots on the surface of the leaf stems and tan flakes attached to the center veins of the leaves. The leaves began turning brown at the tips and edges, and new leaves were not growing.

Two weeks ago, I replanted the tree in a bigger container, filled in with Miracle-Gro Cactus, Palm, and Citrus Potting Mix, and sprayed the tree with BioAdvanced Fungus Control for Lawns. I increased the water to 5 quarts per day, until it runs out the bottom. New leaves are now growing vigorously, but the new stems are still covered with dark brown spots, and the center veins still full of the tan flakes. Can you tell me what it is, and what to do?

[image: Christmas Palm with disease, photo 1]
[image: Christmas Palm with disease, photo 2]

Comment: I don't know about this plant or this condition, but 5 quarts of water per day in a humid environment is overkill, to say the least.